# Proper way to convert string to array of char C++

Tags: c++, string, char, type-conversion

I've been trying to convert string into array of char with C++, but I'm having a hard time to use `c_str()` function and store the char properly.

```
string a = "A20UG008";
string b = "A20UG009";
string c = "A20UG010";
char hi[3][8];
strcpy(hi[0],a.c_str());
strcpy(hi[1],a.c_str());
strcpy(hi[2],a.c_str());
```

output:

```
A20UG008A20UG008A20UG008
```

What I wish to display if I call `hi[0]` is only "A20UG008".

Is there any wrong logical expression or did I use the wrong function?

Comment: You need to allow space for the terminating 0, so you need 9 characters of space for an 8 character string.

Comment: If you open your C++ textbook and read all about literal character strings and how they work, you will discover that `"A20UG008"` is 9 `char`s, and not 8. You will need to fix your code accordingly, see your C++ textbook for more information.

Comment: *what i wish to display if i call hi[0]* -- You didn't show how you are displaying this string.  Even if you didn't correct the issue as pointed out, you can still have the ability to show only 8 characters by adjusting your output function(s) accordingly.  There are some legitimate reasons for *not* storing the null byte in the destination array, so right now, your question needs more detail.

Comment: You don't need to use std::string (C++) with strcpy (left-over unsafe "C") to initialize your fixed size array with text. You should it like this, life example here : https://onlinegdb.com/h3mN28uop

Comment: Your C array is off-by-one. C strings need one extra character for the \0

Answer (score 0):

> Proper way to convert string to array of char C++

A string is already an array of char. There's no need to convert.

> output:
>
> ```
> A20UG008A20UG008A20UG008
> ```

This cannot be the case since copying arrays produces no output.

Comment: Technically, C string needs a \0 at the end, while C++ string does not. C++ String will make sure the \0 is added when calling .c_str()